# array of invalid chars - checking the start of string to validate it does not start with invalid chars

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of invalid strings,

`let invalidStrings = ["070", "0870", "030"]`

I want to check a phone number/string does not start with anything in theinvalidStrings array, I have tried,

```
if (substrings.some(v => str !== v)) {
   // Will only return when the `str` is not included in the `substrings`
}
```

but that checks the entire string for any appearance of an invalidString?

Comment: see: [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: Have you ever tried regular expression and match patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter an array that contains the invalid string by using `filter()`.

```js
let invalidStrings = ["070", "0870", "030"]

let substrings = ["070100", "1107011", "1230870", "030555030", "123456789"]

let filteredStrings = substrings.filter(v => { // filter the array you want to work on
  return invalidStrings.find(iStr => v.startsWith(iStr)) //check if each string contains one of the invalid strings
})

console.log(filteredStrings);
```

Output
`Array [ "070100", "030555030" ]`